# Change "Quit mode" in emacs-mode keys of tmux to C-g

Tags: emacs, tmux

In tmux once in `copy-mode` one can exit either with `Esc` or with `q` (in vi-mode). I would like that to be `C-g`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Turns out](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/f7598b8a267eeab926ed0a934f36595077aab605/mode-key.c#L94) the relevant command is called `cancel` and the [relevant mode](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/f7598b8a267eeab926ed0a934f36595077aab605/mode-key.c#L94) is called `emacs-copy`, thus what did the trick was

```
bind-key -t emacs-copy C-g cancel
```